# Indefinite integral involving the product of two generalized Laguerre polynomials

Tags: indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, orthogonal-polynomials

I am trying to find the indefinite integral

\begin{align}
\int{x^{\alpha +1}e^{-x}\left(L_{m}^{\alpha}(x)\right)^{2}dx}
\end{align}

where $L_{m}^{\alpha}(x)$ is the generalized Laguerre Polynomial, $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$. I found the solution for the [definite](http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LaguerreL3/21/ShowAll.html) integral between 0 and $\infty$, but not the indefinite solution.

Thanks in advance.